# While streaking, can I "shock" police officers?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm working on the Saintsbook challenge for streaking, and occasionally I raise the ire of the police.  Normally I run away from them, seeing as they're shooting at me and I'm rather... vulnerable.  However, it seems like having a high wanted level might make this easier to shock enough people to get to the higher levels.

Do I get credit for shocking police officers (and STAG officers, army soldiers, etc)?

Comment: Just wanted to add that you start the streaking diversion by first visiting a clothing shop or your wardrobe at a crib, and strip bare naked by choosing "none" for all the clothing options.  Exit the clothing interface, then tap down on the D-Pad twice and you'll start the minigame.  I think you can probably get away with wearing *some* clothes, so long as the game is having to pixelate your naughty bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've determined that you can, in fact, shock police and military officers.  In fact, you can shock gang members, and even people driving cars, if you can get close enough.

The Saintsbook challenge is for time though, and the rewards are otherwise uninteresting.  If it's a pain, you're better off just starting streaking, waiting for time to run out, and then starting again.  There's no added benefit to actually doing "well" at the minigame.

Comment: You can even shock police if you have aggro from them. As far as I can tell, the only people you can't shock are fellow Saints, which makes sense: they may already be familiar with your ... gun prowess.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried streaking at the place full of zombies and it was super easy seeing as they all run towards you rather then from you

Comment: But zombies do cause the streak counter to go up?